# JSdom append to body and render as an ejs view

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, jsdom

I wanted to consult on what will be the best approach to achieve the following:

I'm requesting a webpage via the request module, then I throw the body to the
jsdom.env()
function.
What I want in the end is to add a few div, script, and link elements to the document, 
and in the end render it to the user. (basically a proxy with modifying the requested remote server html)

What I initially did was to make an ejs that looks as follow (testenv.ejs):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <%- head %>
   <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
   <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css' />
</head>
<body>
   <%- body %>
   <div id="context-menu-container">
       <div id="context-menu-header"></div>
       <div id="context-menu-options"></div>
       <div id="context-menu-steps"></div>
   </div>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
   <script src="/javascripts/test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I render this view from my route as follows (proxy.js):

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var jsdom = require('jsdom');
var request = require('request');
var jar = request.jar();


/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var url = req.param('url');
    if (url) {
        request({
            url: url,
            jar: jar
        }, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                jsdom.env({
                    html: body,
                    scripts: [
                        'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js'
                    ],
                    done: function (err, window) {
                        var $ = window.jQuery;
                        res.render('testenv.ejs', { head: $('head').html(), body: $('body').html() })
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        res.send("No url param specified...");
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

The problem I have with this approach is that `/stylesheets/style.css` and `/javascripts/test/js` are not downloaded to the client, they're being requested from the remote server and not from the node server.
I tried to fiddle with the order of the javascript and css files I include with in my view and noticed that If I put the css files above the `<%- head>` part they're begin loaded correctly.
As to the javascript files I had to move them to the head as well (something I do not with to do for obvious reasons like delaying the rendering of the page) but as to the javascript files I encountered another problem.
After moving them to the head the `/javascripts/test/js` was being loaded correctly because it was requested from the node server and not from the remote server anymore but the problem is that it depends on the *jquery-ui*,
which for some reason was being loaded but a function of the library was not recognized as if I loaded the `/javascripts/test/js` only after the *jquery-ui* library.

Beside the problems I described, I've thought about a scenario where I request a webpage that has the same css/js file name with the ones I try to load or maybe same framework used (bootstrap/jquery but with different revision) which could lead to conflicts.
It's possible to change the name of the css/js files I load to something unique, but I don't want to leave it to the hands of luck because maybe some other website will have the same file names by chance.
That lead me to think that my approach isn't bulletproof and not the best, so I want to ask what you guys think I should do to achieve my goal.

## EDIT

I pretty much got to a dead end here.
I've been searching for the last week now for what may cause my issue but couldn't find anything useful.
I also noticed while debugging when supplying the url query parameter with www.google.com, I get to the middleware that handles 404 not found routes in my express app *although* it succeeded in rendering the page partly.
This is how the rendered page ended up looking like:
[google rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPwc5.png)

This is how my app.js is set like - webstorm default (app.js):

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');


var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var fxp = require('./routes/fxp')

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/proxy', proxy); // proxy is the the js file above that exports the route that handles the requests to the path /proxy/...

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```